# laravel 6 config vite rollupoption and how to config laravel resources/js/ssr.js to generate ssr.mjs

Tags: server-side-rendering, laravel-6, inertiajs

laravel version 6
vite config

export default defineConfig({
base: '/js',
publicDir: './public/js',
rollupOutputOptions: {
format: "esm",
},
resolve: {
alias: {
'@popperjs/core': '@popperjs/core/dist/esm/popper'
}
},

```
build: {
    modulePreload: {
        polyfill: true,
    },
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    manifest: true,
    outDir: './public/js',
    assetsDir: '',
    // publicPath:'./assets333/',
    commonjsOptions: {
        transformMixedEsModules: true
    },
    rollupOptions: {

        input: [
            'resources/views/ssr/index.js',


        ],



plugins: [
    // 使用 uglify-js 进行代码压缩
    laravel({
        input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
        ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.js',
        refresh: true,
    }),
```

but it does't work ,can't gernate ssr.mjs  /i want use it to to ssr start server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocCP7.png)

when i run the command   php artisan inertia:start-ssr

item remands me to gernate ssr.mjs